# Numpy 3D Matrix Multiplication (Same Dimensions)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 3d, multiplication

I am trying to multiply two 3D matrices with the same dimensions (MxNxD). I know in 2D matrix multiplication, I can just transpose one and do the matrix multiplication. Is there a similar approach for this with 3D matrices? I'm not really sure how I can multiply the two. I don't really understand how np.einsum works or how I could use it.

Comment: Are you trying to do it element-wise? If not, what would be the resulting shape?

Comment: What's the desired result shape?

Comment: what's the sum-of-products dimension?  Is one dimension a 'batch' one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you want the "multiplication" to do. One possible approach is:

```py
import numpy as np

M = 10
N = 20
D = 30

A = np.random.rand(M, N, D)
B = np.random.rand(M, N, D)

C = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', A, B)
print(C.shape) # (10, 20)
```

But you can do many more, for example:

```py
C = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->jk', A, B)
print(C.shape) # (20, 30)

C = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', A, B)
print(C.shape) # (10, 30)
```

Or simply element-wise multiplication:

```
C = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ijk', A, B)
print(C.shape) # (10, 20, 30)
```